# Referencing a project in a parent directory from my Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core

So I have a .NET 6 solution structured like so:

```
MySolution
|
+-- RecipeManagement
|
+---- src
|
+------ RecipeManagement
|
+-------- RecipeManagement.csproj
|
+-------- Dockerfile
|
+---- tests
|
+------ RecipeManagement.IntegrationTests
|
+-------- RecipeManagement.IntegrationTests.csproj
|
+------ RecipeManagement.UnitTests
|
+-------- RecipeManagement.UnitTests.csproj
|
+-- SharedKernel
|
+---- SharedKernel.csproj
|
+-- dockercompose.yaml
```

I'm having trouble getting my Dockerfile to properly reference my `SharedKernel` class project.

Without the SharedKernel, something like this usually works fine:

dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["RecipeManagement.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./RecipeManagement.csproj"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build "RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build-env AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/RecipeManagement.dll"]
```

compose:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  recipemanagement-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '52450:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=dev_recipemanagement
    volumes:
      - recipemanagement-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  recipemanagement-api:
    build:
      context: ./RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "52451:8080"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
      DB_CONNECTION_STRING: "Host=recipemanagement-db;Port=5432;Database=dev_recipemanagement;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"

    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
        
volumes:
  recipemanagement-data:
```

But, once I try to bring in the SharedKernel, it gets unhappy. Note the differences:

1. Updated `context` and `dockerfile` path in compose
2. Updated `Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers` section to account for new context and project

dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj", "RecipeManagement/"]
COPY ["SharedKernel/SharedKernel.csproj", "SharedKernel/"]
RUN dotnet restore "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build "RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build-env AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/RecipeManagement.dll"]
```

compose:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  recipemanagement-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '52450:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=dev_recipemanagement
    volumes:
      - recipemanagement-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  recipemanagement-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "52451:8080"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
      DB_CONNECTION_STRING: "Host=recipemanagement-db;Port=5432;Database=dev_recipemanagement;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"

    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
        
volumes:
  recipemanagement-data:
```

The result here being that it can't find the file for some reason:

```
------
 > [build 5/8] RUN dotnet restore "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj":
#13 0.374 MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
#13 0.374 Switch: RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj
------
```

> Potentially of note, if i just adjust the context and dockerfile path with the original project that doesn't have a shared kernel, i start getting yelled at about my test projects not being included

### Edit

In response to the answer from @Paolo, I tried both of the below dockerfiles running `docker build -f RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/Dockerfile .` from my root `MySolution` directory and get the same error. I've tried a few different dockerfile iterations. see two below:

one iteration:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj", "RecipeManagement/"]
COPY ["SharedKernel/SharedKernel.csproj", "SharedKernel/"]
RUN dotnet restore "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build "RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build-env AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/RecipeManagement.dll"]
```

second iteration:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj", "RecipeManagement/"]
COPY ["SharedKernel/SharedKernel.csproj", "SharedKernel/"]
RUN dotnet restore "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RecipeManagement"
RUN dotnet build "RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RecipeManagement.dll"]
```

** Update: if i change
`RUN dotnet restore "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj"`
to
`RUN dotnet restore "RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj"`

in option 2 it gets past the error, but wants to build all my tests

Comment: What's the docker build command you are using?

Comment: `docker-compose up --build` from the root where the compose file is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so i updated it to have the copy paths mirror my solution paths and that seemed to do the trick! also had a typo in http vs https but that's seprate :-)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj", "./RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/"]
COPY ["SharedKernel/SharedKernel.csproj", "./SharedKernel/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build-env AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/RecipeManagement.dll"]
```

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  recipemanagement-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '52450:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=dev_recipemanagement
    volumes:
      - recipemanagement-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  recipemanagement-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "52451:8080"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
      DB_CONNECTION_STRING: "Host=recipemanagement-db;Port=5432;Database=dev_recipemanagement;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"

    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
        
volumes:
  recipemanagement-data:
```